# java 8 double findFirst on stream

Tags: java

I have a `HashMap` that contains a single value which is an `ArrayList` that also contains a single value as well. I need to extract the single value from the `ArrayList`. At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```java
map.values()
   .stream()
   .findFirst()
   .orElse(new ArrayList<>()).stream().findFirst().orElse(null)
```

This works, but I hope for a more elegant way to get the first element of a stream inside the first element of a stream.
In other words, I want eliminate the double `stream().findFirst()`.
Is that possible?

Comment: Will they always have a single value? Why not just store that value directly if so?

Comment: it comes from a cms, in this mapping there is always a single value, but I can't store is directly. The cms is pretty old and has a weird structure.

Comment: I think the most correct solution is avoiding a stream, using a simply `#isEmpty` check on the map, followed by `map.values().iterator().next()`, another `#isEmpty`, and then returning the value if it is there. This can be encapsulated in a method, and would be less of an overhead than constructing multiple streams. If you stick with the stream solution, `Collections.emptyList()` would be better than `new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: You could use `map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).findFirst().orElse(null)` and avoid creating an empty list.

Comment: Using `flatMap(List::Stream)` sounds like good idea. I'm also a fan of Google Guava's [`MoreCollectors.onlyElement()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html#onlyElement()) collector which gives you the only element in the stream and throws if there are none or if there are more than one, both of which is a useful invariant. That'd look like: `map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(MoreCollectors.onlyElement())`.